# Import/export by sector/country data source

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade, data-request, balance-of-trade

I am looking for import/exports data by sector and country, with partner countries. The goal is to get a picture of overall imports/exports to/from a specific country with (possibly) all of its partners, for any particular sector/year.

So for example: For 2017, oil imports and exports for China with Russia, Angola, Saudi Arabia, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the [UN Comtrade database](https://comtrade.un.org/) is the main data source for this kind of query with substantial country coverage.  It's broken down by [HS code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonized_System).

It has its issues.  Reporting is based on national authorities, so you should usually expect data on imports to be more accurate than exports because of the tax implications (so Uganda's imports from Kenya are likely to be more accurate than Kenya's exports to Uganda).

Comment: The direction of inaccuracy pertaining to imports/exports could depend on the context. Where governments heavily rely on border taxes on imports to finance critical expenditures, your statement is (almost) certainly correct. However, there are also cases where export taxes comprise much of revenues (e.g., resource exports) and basically the same logic applies, to exports instead. Also, in other cases evading import taxes is near to impossible whereas other factors may explain unregistered export activities. Very important aspect that you raise, though, in my opinion.